# diff to output only the file names

Tags: linux, command-line, diff

I'm looking to run a Linux command that will recursively compare two directories and output **only** the file names of what is different. This includes anything that is present in one directory and not the other or vice versa, and text differences.

Answer (score 478, accepted):

From the diff man page:

> **`-q`**   Report only whether the files differ, not the details of the differences.
>   **`-r`**   When comparing directories, recursively compare any subdirectories found.

Example command:

```
diff -qr dir1 dir2
```

Example output (depends on locale):

```
$ ls dir1 dir2
dir1:
same-file  different  only-1

dir2:
same-file  different  only-2
$ diff -qr dir1 dir2
Files dir1/different and dir2/different differ
Only in dir1: only-1
Only in dir2: only-2
```

Comment: Thanks - the `diff` man page in CentOS 7 describes `-q` as "report only when files differ", which is less clear than what you wrote.

Comment: This compares the actual content of the files which is often what one wants, however, the rsync answer gives the option to only look at the file names and sizes, and not the content; that is sometimes desirable.

Comment: Works on macOS, too.

Comment: Also, can include `-x PATTERN` in command to exclude certain subdirectories. For example, `diff -qr repo1 repo2 -x ".git" ` will compare two directories but will exclude file paths with ".git" in them.

Answer (score 46):

You can also use rsync

```
rsync -rv --size-only --dry-run /my/source/ /my/dest/ > diff.out
```

Comment: `--size-only` will miss files of identical size but different content, e.g. _old/version.txt_ **"29a"** _new/version.txt_ **"29b"**. Use instead: `rsync -ric --dry-run old/ new/` where the "-i" argument allows to obtain the file list directly via `rsync -ric --dry-run old/ new/ | cut -d" " -f 2`

Comment: This is great if you are only looking for missing files (especially across network shares), *because* it doesn't compare the contents.  This helped me find a few files that failed when migrating to a new NAS.

Comment: Be sure to include the trailing slash for paths specified on rsync's command line. WIthout them, this won't work correctly, and rsync will likely just enumerate all file names!

Comment: With regard to the comments on not checking the content. This is sometimes desirable, at least as first pass.

Comment: @OverZealous Yes, but the odds are good that the size won't be the same to the byte. Still, I would just exclude the `--size-only` to check full contents.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to get a list of files that are only in one directory and not their sub directories and only their file names:

```
diff -q /dir1 /dir2 | grep /dir1 | grep -E "^Only in*" | sed -n 's/[^:]*: //p'
```

If you want to recursively list all the files and directories that are different with their full paths:

```
diff -rq /dir1 /dir2 | grep -E "^Only in /dir1*" | sed -n 's/://p' | awk '{print $3"/"$4}'
```

This way you can apply different commands to all the files.

For example I could remove all the files and directories that are in dir1 but not dir2:

```
diff -rq /dir1 /dir2 | grep -E "^Only in /dir1*" | sed -n 's/://p' | awk '{print $3"/"$4}' xargs -I {} rm -r {}
```

Answer (score 13):

The approach of running `diff -qr old/ new/` has one major drawback: it may miss files in newly created directories. E.g. in the example below the file `data/pages/playground/playground.txt` is not in the output of  `diff -qr old/ new/` whereas the directory `data/pages/playground/` is (search for **playground.txt** in your browser to quickly compare). I also posted the following solution [on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192305/107886), but I'll copy it here as well:

To create a list of new or modified files programmatically the best solution I could come up with is using **rsync**, **sort**, and **uniq**:

```
(rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/ && rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" new/ old/) | sort | uniq
```

Let me explain with this example: we want to compare two dokuwiki releases to see which files were changed and which ones were newly created.

We fetch the tars with wget and extract them into the directories `old/` and `new/`:

```
wget http://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-2014-09-29d.tgz
wget http://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-2014-09-29.tgz
mkdir old && tar xzf dokuwiki-2014-09-29.tgz -C old --strip-components=1
mkdir new && tar xzf dokuwiki-2014-09-29d.tgz -C new --strip-components=1
```

Running rsync one way might miss newly created files as the comparison of rsync and diff shows here:

```
rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/
```

*yields the following output:*

```
VERSION
doku.php
conf/mime.conf
inc/auth.php
inc/lang/no/lang.php
lib/plugins/acl/remote.php
lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php
lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php
```

Running rsync only in one direction misses the newly created files and the other way round would miss deleted files, compare the output of diff:

```
diff -qr old/ new/
```

*yields the following output:*

```
Files old/VERSION and new/VERSION differ
Files old/conf/mime.conf and new/conf/mime.conf differ
Only in new/data/pages: playground
Files old/doku.php and new/doku.php differ
Files old/inc/auth.php and new/inc/auth.php differ
Files old/inc/lang/no/lang.php and new/inc/lang/no/lang.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/acl/remote.php and new/lib/plugins/acl/remote.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php and new/lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php differ
Files old/lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php and new/lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php differ
```

Running rsync both ways and sorting the output to remove duplicates reveals that the directory `data/pages/playground/` and the file `data/pages/playground/playground.txt` were missed initially:

```
(rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" old/ new/ && rsync -rcn --out-format="%n" new/ old/) | sort | uniq
```

*yields the following output:*

```
VERSION
conf/mime.conf
data/pages/playground/
data/pages/playground/playground.txt
doku.php
inc/auth.php
inc/lang/no/lang.php
lib/plugins/acl/remote.php
lib/plugins/authplain/auth.php
lib/plugins/usermanager/admin.php
```

`rsync` is run with theses arguments:

- `-r` to "recurse into directories",
- `-c` to also compare files of identical size and only "skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size",
- `-n` to "perform a trial run with no changes made", and
- `--out-format="%n"` to "output updates using the specified FORMAT", which is "%n" here for the file name only

The output (list of files) of `rsync` in both directions is combined and sorted using `sort`, and this sorted list is then condensed by removing all duplicates with `uniq`

Comment: Couldn't you just run it backwards (`diff new/ old/`) to see which directories were deleted?

Comment: Running `diff -qr new/ old/` on the example above with the dokuwiki tars produces the same output as `diff -qr old/ new/` – i.e. you see that the directory is new/missing but not the files in it

Answer (score 12):

On my linux system to get *just* the filenames

```
diff -q /dir1 /dir2|cut -f2 -d' '
```

Comment: I don't put filenames with spaces on my linux system. ;)

Comment: I did not mean to impute this to you... ;-p
Just as a hint for somebody who does...

Comment: does not work for me. My directory structure is like below `audit-0.0.234/audit-data-warehouse-0.0.234/ audit-0.0.235/audit-data-warehouse-0.0.235/`

Comment: `diff -qrN /dir1 /dir2 | cut -f2 -d' '` works fine for me!

Answer (score 2):

I have a directory.

```sh
$ tree dir1
dir1
├── a
│   └── 1.txt
├── b
│   └── 2.txt
└── c
    ├── 3.txt
    ├── 4.txt
    └── d
        └── 5.txt

4 directories, 5 files
```

I have another directory.

```sh
$ tree dir2
dir2
├── a
│   └── 1.txt
├── b
└── c
    ├── 3.txt
    ├── 5.txt
    └── d
        └── 5.txt

4 directories, 4 files
```

I can diff two directories.

```sh
$ diff <(cd dir1; find . -type f | sort) <(cd dir2; find . -type f| sort)
--- /dev/fd/11  2022-01-21 20:27:15.000000000 +0900
+++ /dev/fd/12  2022-01-21 20:27:15.000000000 +0900
@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
 ./a/1.txt
-./b/2.txt
 ./c/3.txt
-./c/4.txt
+./c/5.txt
 ./c/d/5.txt
```

Comment: This approach is nice, but only lists files that do not exist on the one side or the other. In order to actually list files that are different, you could extend the approach by computing a checksum of each file before diffing the lists:

`diff <(cd dir1; find . -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | sort)  <(cd dir2; find . -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | sort)` . You might want to extract the command to a script as it's getting quite long.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was looking for a way to compare file structures of 2 projects. Thanks!

Answer (score -5):

```
rsync -rvc --delete --size-only --dry-run source dir target dir
```